# Text Mining with R

Tags: r, text-mining

I need help in text mining using R

```
Title      Date            Content    
Boy        May 13 2015     "She is pretty", Tom said. Tom is handsome.
Animal     June 14 2015    The penguin is cute, lion added.
Human      March 09 2015   Mr Koh predicted that every human is smart...
Monster    Jan 22 2015     Ms May, a student, said that John has $10.80. May loves you.
```

I would just want to get the opinions from what the people had said.

And also, I would like to seek help in getting the percentage (Eg. 9.8%), because when i split the sentences based on fullstop ("."), i would get "His result improved by 0." instead of "His result improved by 0.8%".

Below is the output that I would like to obtain:

```
Title      Date            Content    
Boy        May 13 2015     she is pretty
Animal     June 14 2015    the penguin is cute
Human      March 09 2015   every human is smart
Monster    Jan 22 2015     john has $10.80
```

Below is the code that I tried, but didn't get desired output:

```
list <- c("said", "added", "predicted")
pattern <- paste (list, collapse = "|")
dataframe <- stack(setNames(lapply(strsplit(dataframe, '(?<=[.])', perl=TRUE), grep, pattern = pattern, value = TRUE), dataframe$Title))[2:1]
```

Comment: This is potentially a very big job and you will likely need some AI for fishing out what you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi, can you guide me in doing this? And what is AI? Thanks.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you are going to need to either use or build a text parser which can actually understand English grammar.  This is no small endeavor, and it is too big for a single Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but your regular expression for splitting is wrong. This gave the correct arrangement for the data, modulo your request to extract opinions more exactly:

```
txt <- '
Title      Date            Content    
Boy        May 13 2015     "She is pretty", Tom said. Tom is handsome.
Animal     June 14 2015    The penguin is cute, lion added.
Human      March 09 2015   Mr Koh predicted that every human is smart...
Monster    Jan 22 2015     Ms May, a student, said that John has $10.80. May loves you.
'

txt <- gsub(" {2,}(?=\\S)", "|", txt, perl = TRUE)
dataframe <- read.table(sep = "|", text = txt, header = TRUE)

list <- c("said", "added", "predicted")
pattern <- paste (list, collapse = "|")

content <- strsplit(dataframe$Content, '\\.(?= )', perl=TRUE)
opinions <- lapply(content, grep, pattern = pattern, value = TRUE)
names(opinions) <- dataframe$Title
result <- stack(opinions)
```

In your sample data, all full stops followed by spaces are sentence-ending, so that's what the regular expression `\.(?= )` matches. However that will break up sentences like `"I was born in the U.S.A. but I live in Canada"`, so you might have to do additional pre-processing and checking.

Then, assuming the `Title`s are unique identifiers, you can just `merge` to add the dates back in:

```
result <- merge(dataframe[c("Title", "Date")], result, by = "Title")
```

As mentioned in the comments, the NLP task itself has more to do with text parsing than R programming. You can probably get some mileage out of searching for a pattern like

```
<optional adjectives> <noun> <verb> <optional adverbs> <adjective> <optional and/or> <optional adjective> ...
```

which would match your sample data, but I'm far from an expert here. You'd also need a dictionary with lexical categories. A Google search for "extract opinion text" yielded a lot of helpful results on the first page, including [this site](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html) run by Bing Liu. From what I can tell, Professor Liu literally wrote the book on sentiment analysis.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. What about full stops that are not followed by spaces eg. He is sad.She is angry. Thanks @ssdecontrol

Comment: @poppp Like I said, you will need to figure out the regular expression that works for your case. Another possibility would be "full stops not followed by a digit", i.e. `\.(?=\D)`, but again that will split on abbreviations. But then you could pre-process by removing periods from known acronyms, or from sequences of the form `([A-Z]\.){2,}`